# Could the black order disappear when Thanos snaps his fingers?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Of course, all members of the black order are dead when Thanos snaps his fingers in *Avengers: Infinity War*. But could it be possible that if they were still alive they also randomly disappear?

If so - why are they helping him? When Thanos snaps his fingers he could also be randomly chosen to die, but he has the Infinity Gauntlet, he can resurrect himself after that. The members of the black order couldn't.

Does Thanos ensure that the black order will be omitted by the snap or are they rather fanatically devoted to Thanos's mission and also take the option that they disappear?

It will be better if you could provide an answer from the movie, but if it's impossible, from comics will also be interesting. ;)

Comment: Hello. Welcome to [movies.se]. This site is only for films. Questions and answers from Comic books is out of scope for us. You could try [fantasy.se] if you're looking for comics.

Comment: How *could* it be possible to provide an explanation from the movie? As you said, they're already dead by then and their fate is not shown, neither does the film go into great detail about how *exactly* the snap works. But really people, we have to get off that trip of trying to find out if every single dude and their grandma would have been affected by the finger snap and how its exact statistical distribution works. Because what's the point? The film simply doesn't have the aspiration to provide a detailed rundown of who exactly died and why, let alone who *would possibly* die.

Comment: There might, however, very well be a reasonable question about the motivation of the black order and their dedication to Thanos' goals hidden under this what-iffery. But I'd implore you to try and flesh that out of it without us having to prove its premise of how exactly the infinity gauntlet operates, because that's neither doable nor useful.

Comment: @NogShine That isn't exactly true either, though. In general we very much entertain answers from the comics here, provided they relate to the film and help explaining that.

Comment: As I said over on SFF please don't [cross post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/197005/58193). If you want the question here delete the one on SFF, if you want it on SFF delete this one.

Comment: As I understand I can't delete this question because people puts effort to answer it.

Comment: @KamilJędryczek any thoughts are welcome bud, thumb up for the question !!

Comment: Is it ever stated, either by Thanos or anyone else, that the half is completely random and Thanos has no control over who is in each half?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We see how much the black order is dedicated to Thanos, calling him father, and dedication towards him and his mission.
Ebony Maw is so powerful himself, but acts as a servant (right hand) of the Mad-Titan.

Ebony knows its not possible for just anyone to wield them infinity stones even if one collects them all.He sees THAT might and nobility in Thanos.He is confident of what all Thanos can do bare-handed when he stops Cull from reaching out to help thanos while fighting Hulk.

I feel that the black order has accepted the fact that there is no stopping Thanos.One can either stand by him or die facing him, as he is ready to do ANYTHING to achieve his goal.(he killed/sacrificed his fav daughter).

Anyone of them would be happy to give away their life before or after the snap for Thanos.